# Salesforce-to-Salesforce REST Callout works for Account but Not Opportunity; "Malformed JSON" Error

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, json, callout

I'm trying to integrate two (developer) salesforce instances, such that records created in one are automatically created in ("pushed into") the other.  My code for doing this to *accounts* works.  Now I'm trying to do the same for *opportunities* (i.e. the real requirement), but - despite that code being almost identical to the code for accounts - it doesn't work.

In the originating org, for **accounts**, I have the following trigger and class:

```
Trigger SendAccount_Trigger on Account (after insert) {
    for(Account a : Trigger.new){
        SendAccount.createAccount(a.name, a.Phone, a.Website);
    }
}

public class SendAccount {

    String clientId = '***************************************************************';
    String clientsecret ='*******************';
    String username='fake@fake.com';
    String password = '******************************************';
    String accesstoken_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String authurl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';

    public class deserializeResponse {

        public String id;
        public String access_token;

    }

    public String ReturnAccessToken(SendAccount Acc){

        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='
        +clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;

        Http h= new Http();
        HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST'); 
        req.setEndpoint('https://na50.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        HttpResponse res=h.send(req);

        deserializeResponse resp1= (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);

        return resp1.access_token;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void createAccount(String Accname, String Phone, String Website){

        SendAccount acc1 = new SendAccount();

        String accessToken = acc1.ReturnAccessToken(acc1);

        if(accessToken!=null){

            String endPoint='https://na50.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account';             

            String jsonstr='{"Name":"'+ Accname +'","Phone":"'+ Phone +'","Website":"'+ Website +'"}';

            Http h2 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
            req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req2.setHeader('accept','application/json');
            req2.setBody(jsonstr);
            req2.setMethod('POST');
            req2.setEndpoint(endPoint);

            HttpResponse res2 = h2.send(req2);

            deserializeResponse deresp=(deserializeResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, for **opportunities**, I have the following trigger and class:

```
trigger SendOpp_Trigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        SendOpportunity.createOpportunity(o.name, o.Account_External_Id__c, o.CloseDate, o.StageName);
    }
}

public class SendOpportunity {

    String clientId = '***************************************************************';
    String clientsecret ='*******************';
    String username='fake@fake.com';
    String password = '******************************************';
    String accesstoken_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String authurl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';

    public class deserializeResponse {

        public String id;
        public String access_token;

    }

    public String ReturnAccessToken(SendOpportunity Opp){

        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='
        +clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;

        Http h= new Http();
        HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST'); 
        req.setEndpoint('https://na50.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        HttpResponse res=h.send(req);

        deserializeResponse resp1= (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);

        return resp1.access_token;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void createOpportunity(String oppName, String acctId, Date d, String stage){

        SendOpportunity opp1 = new SendOpportunity();

        String accessToken = opp1.ReturnAccessToken(opp1);

        if(accessToken!=null){

            String endPoint='https://na50.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity';             

            String jsonstr='{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","Account_External_Id__c":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ d +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';

            Http h2 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
            req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req2.setHeader('accept','application/json');
            req2.setBody(jsonstr);
            req2.setMethod('POST');
            req2.setEndpoint(endPoint);

            HttpResponse res2 = h2.send(req2);

            deserializeResponse deresp=(deserializeResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive in the debug log when I create an opportunity is:

```
Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object
```

On:

```
deserializeResponse deresp = (deserializeResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);
```

My best guess so far is that the error has something to do with the `endPoint` variable  and/or (most likely) my `jsonstr` variable.

If it's `jsonstr`, what's wrong with it?

Look at how it compares in the two classes:

```
'{"Name":"'+ Accname +'","Phone":"'+ Phone +'","Website":"'+ Website +'"}';

'{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","Account_External_Id__c":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ d +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';
```

Does Opportunity have a different JSON structure or is the problem something else?

Comment: What's the actual text of the response body that you get back?

Comment: As suggested above can you do a system.debug(res2.getBody()); and post the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in your JSON. From the trigger you are passing the date to the createOpportunity method. Could you try converting the date to string and then pass like,

```
'{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","Account_External_Id__c":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ String.valueOf(d) +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';
```

Also, do you have the `Account_External_Id__c` field created on the target SF org?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

David and Kostadin, your's was a huge clue.

`system.debug(res2.getBody());` printed:

```
{"message":"No such column 'Account_External_Id__c' on sobject of type Opportunity","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}
```

Shailesh, you were right.  I hadn't created `Account_External_Id__c` in the target org, so that was the next thing I did.  But then I also got the following text back, validating your suggestion to convert the date to String:

```
{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value 2018-02-28 00:00:00 or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:51]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}
```

So I followed your suggestion and that brought me closer to my goal.

The opportunity was finally successfully created in the target org, but it wasn't related to an account (i.e. the account lookup wasn't populated) like I intended - even though:

- The **External Id** on the source account was populated with the Id of the target account
- The **Account External Id** on the opportunity (cross-object-formula field) was populated
- The class in the target org, which passes the values to the opportunity instance, was correctly passing **Account External Id** to **AccountId**

Ultimately the solution was to use the `AccountId` field directly, implemented in the following changes:

**SendOpportunity** class / *Source* org:

```
String jsonstr='{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","Account_External_Id__c":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ String.valueOf(d) +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';
```

to

```
String jsonstr='{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","AccountId":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ String.valueOf(d) +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';
```

**REST_OpportunityService** class / *target* org:

```
    @HttpPost
    global static OppWrapper doPost(String oppName, String acctId, Date d, String stage) {
```

to

```
    @HttpPost
    global static OppWrapper doPost(String oppName, Id acctId, Date d, String stage) {
```

My trigger in the source org stayed the same:

```
trigger SendOpp_Trigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        SendOpportunity.createOpportunity(o.name, o.Account_External_Id__c, o.CloseDate, o.StageName);
    }
}
```

Thanks, all, for your help.